# CSS-Grid Layout like Shutterstock

Tags: javascript, html, css

i what to have a grid layout for displaying images.
so how can i have a grid layout like Shutterstock to have dynamic width and height

i tried this but it's not the same

```
.gridsys{
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(250px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: 300px 200px;
}
```

this is the whole code:

```
<div class="gridsys">
   <div class="item">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300/?random">
   </div>
</div>
.item{
    img{
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      object-fit: cover;
    }
    @media (min-width: 480px) {
      &:first-child {
        grid-area: 1 / 1 / span 2 / span 2;
      }
    }
}
```

i want to have something like this:
https://www.shutterstock.com/featured-collections/fathers-day-187157459

Comment: what you are looking for is called masonry layout, here is a pen showcasing it: : https://codepen.io/balazs_sziklai/pen/mOwoLg

Comment: @ImmortalDude Thank you for your time.i think width of every item in the row is not explicit in Shutterstock. am i right?

Comment: Yes, it's like Google images, and is quite easy without the need of grids, just specify a height for the container of the image then set an overflow to it, then set width 100% to the image itself, thereby achieveing the desired effect

Comment: @ImmortalDude OMG!! why i didn't mention google image instead of Shutterstock. you're awesome. thank you

Comment: No problem, happy to help :)

Comment: FWIW, here's how Shutterstock does it: https://tech.shutterstock.com/2019/03/05/building-a-brick-grid-in-react